# Opera VPN Selenium Web driver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, vpn, test-automation, chromium

Как при запуске operadriver по умолчанию включать opera vpn?

Может можно как-то это автоматизировать ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно создавать разные профили и на каждом профиле подключать vpn от определенной страны.

Запускаем оперу с cmdline параметрами `"--user-data-dir=C:\_opera_data_" + vpnCountries`. Каждый запуск отдельного `--user-data-dir` создает новые сохранения настроек. Нужно вручную заходить в каждый `--user-data-dir+vpnCountries` (то есть запускать оперу с таким параметром) и устанавливать vpn через определенную страну. После выхода из браузера настройки включенного vpn остаются в `--user-data-dir+vpnCountries`. И при следующем запуске оперы с параметром `--user-data-dir+vpnCountries` включается тот впн, который был использован до прошлого закрытия.

*P.S. Способ конечно Угг. Но ничего рабочего и другого мне никто не предложил, пришлось придумать такое "ухищрение"..*

```
public static IWebDriver StartWebDriver()
{
    IWebDriver webDriver;

    OperaOptions oo = new OperaOptions();

    string vpnCountries = GetRandomString("vpn-countries.txt");

    //MessageBox.Show(vpnCountries);

    oo.AddArgument(@"--user-data-dir=C:\_opera_data_" + vpnCountries);

    oo.AddArgument("--private");



    oo.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe";

    webDriver = new OperaDriver(oo);


    return webDriver;
}
```